# Обработка событий js в tilda

Tags: javascript, javascript-events, middleware, tilda

Каким образом в js поставить middleware на событие? Есть событие, а хочется сверху на него навесить ещё одно, которое будет выполняться после.

Пример. У меня есть форма на тильде. Она уже заинтегрирована с моим сервисом. Но помимо прочего, мне нужно сразу после отправки сообщения сделать редирект.

Comment: `setTimeout(..., 1)`?

Comment: Можно скомбинировать обработчик событий с promise. Приходит событие, в обработчике делается future с необходимой обработкой. future оборачивается в promise, на завершение которого навешивается другой future -- редирект. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу на вопрос про `tilda`. Именно он фигурировал в примере. Ответ есть [здесь](http://help-ru.tilda.ws/tips/javascript).

Вам следует использовать аналогичный скрипт. Он связывает с отправкой формы событие через `callback`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {window.mySuccessFunction = function ($form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://example.com",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = `https://example.com`;

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                window.location.href = `https://example.com`;
            }  
        });

    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".js-form-proccess").each(function () {
            $(this).data("success-callback", "window.mySuccessFunction");
        });
    }, 10000);
});
</script>
```

По ссылке можно найти примеры, как отправлять данные формы и другие, аналогичные. Вопрос в том, что здесь отправляются данные с помощью `ajax`, но есть также механизм веб-хуков, который тоже отправляется данные. С одной стороны, он не будет светить url, на который делается запрос. С другой стороны, запрос будет асинхронным и может возникнуть проблема с консистентсностью.

**Пример**

Делается запрос с помощью веб-хука на регистрацию. Далее делается редирект на страицу с логином. Тогда может оказаться, что редирект на страницу с логином произошёл раньше, чем отработал веб-хук и логин не произошёл. В связи с этим, требуется последовательный набор действий. Сначала -- регистрация. Потом -- логин. Т.е. всё должно быть синхронно.

Answer (score 0):

Если обычный редирект, то это делается в настройках («Контент») на самой тильде.

Если нужно показать сообщение об успехе после редирект, то можно воспользоваться [этим решением](https://necodim.ru/tilda/form-redirection-timeout), а внутрь этого скрипта уже поместить всё своё, что необходимо.

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/685402)

Comment: К сожалению (или к счастью), у Тильды много форм. Для каждой формы свой скрипт. Писать сюда скрипт для каждой формы – это ещё хуже, чем дать ссылку на свой ресурс, к которому я очень бережно отношусь :)
Хотя прекрасно понимаю, что всякое может быть. Спасибо за комментарий, в будущем учту.